# Connector_db2 for IBM DB2 iseries

Tags: angular, db2, angular8

I was trying to look at the npm ibm-db or connector_db2 modules on the internet to connect to the databases on IBM System Power I8, but I can't get away, can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to connect to Db2 on iSeries from a non-iSeries system then the ibm_db module on NPM (https://www.npmjs.com/package/ibm_db) should work fine.  There is some instruction which I'm copying here for requirements to connect to either Db2 on i or Z.

*For connectivity against DB2 for LUW or Informix Server using node-ibm_db, no license file is required. However, if you want to use node-ibm_db against DB2 for z/OS or DB2 for i(AS400) Servers, you must have db2connect license of version 11.1 if server is not db2connectactivated to accept unlimited number of client connection. You can buy db2connect license from IBM. The connectivity can be enabled either on server using db2connectactivate utility or on client using client side license file. If you have client side license file, just copy it under .../ibm_db/installer/clidriver/license folder to be effective.
To know more about license and purchasing cost, please contact IBM Customer Support.*